# How to access std::vector<enum> in qml?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

The TestMethod of c++ is called in qml.

c++

```
class Test : public QObject {

    Q_OBJECT
public:

    enum TestEnum
    {
       RED = 0,
       BLACK = 0x1,
       YELLOW = 0x2,
       PINK = 0x4,
    };

    Q_ENUM(TestEnum)

    Q_INVOKABLE std::vector<TestEnum> testMethod();
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(std::vector<Test::TestEnum>)
```

qml

```
    Test{
        id: test
    }


onClicked: {
  var result = test.testMethod();
}
```

It is return error.
qml:384: Error: Unknown method return type: std::vector<Test::TestEnum>.

How do I can solve this problem?

Comment: try with `QVector`(or `QList`) instead of `std::vector`

Comment: Please consider this: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html

Comment: @eyllanesc I tried with QVector and QList. both return error.

Comment: @Vasilij I wrote the code referring to the page.

Comment: Try QVariantList first - this must work and be accessible as an array in javascipt.

Comment: @Vasilij thanks. QVariantList is works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved with QVariantList

Answer (score 1):

You also need to register your class and vector to use them in QML

```
class Test : public QObject {

    Q_OBJECT
public:

    enum TestEnum
    {
       RED = 0,
       BLACK = 0x1,
       YELLOW = 0x2,
       PINK = 0x4,
    };

    Q_ENUM(TestEnum)

    Q_INVOKABLE std::vector<Test::TestEnum> testMethod();
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(std::vector<Test::TestEnum>)
```

in main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    qmlRegisterType<Test>("org.mytest.test", 1, 0, "Test");
    qRegisterMetaType<std::vector<Test::TestEnum>>();
    ....
```

and in qml:

```
import org.mytest.test 1.0

Page {
    width: 600
    height: 400

    Test {
        id: test
    }

    title: qsTr("Page 1")

    Label {
        text: test.testMethod() == Test.RED?"RED":"not red";
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it is not works. It also returns an error. Unknown method return type: std::vector<TestEnum>

Comment: Clean your build. It works.  it also should be std::vector<Test::TestEnum> not std::vector<TestEnum> https://drive.google.com/file/d/16iotXak2vWWuKzoED1BBCr6yNYJ75UkI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: ah, ok. 
test.testMethod() == Test.RED?"RED":"not red"; is works. but I don't want it. 
This code checks only one value.
testMethod() return multiple enum values.
(testMethod() return RED and BLACK and PINK)
I want to handle values in qml.